# Will key-value arguments be evaluated in the order they are given?

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments, key-value

Can one be sure that key-value arguments will put in the dictionary (`kv` below) in the order they are given, and that the dictionary will be iterated in that order too? In this peculiar example it matters:

```
def func(**kv):
    s = 0
    for key in kv:
        s += func2(key,kv[key])

def func2(key,val):
    if key=="all":
        a=val
        b=val
    elif key=="a":
        a = val
    elif key=="a":
        b = val
    return a+b
a=b=0
func(all=3,a=2,b=1)
```

Comment: In Python >= 3.7, yes. The order of keyword arguments is guaranteed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/10629482